# jquery ajax to load html with javascript functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, scripting, insert

I use jquery ajax functions to dynamically load and insert to the DOM some html content with javascript content.
My question is about the performance and memory-leaks, if any.

The dynamically-loaded script content, is created server-side. i.e, The user choose some things, clicks a button, and then get the content based on his choices inserted into the DOM.

So just to make it simple: what happen if a function is inserted into the DOM, then replaced with another function with the same name, which has a different content?

I know that it will override the previous function, but is that creates memory-leaks? other side-effects?
More generally, when a script content is removed from the DOM, does the GC will clean the variables which removed from the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Once initialized, the function will not be deleted even if you delete it from the DOM.

For the memory leak it depends :
If the same variable is replaced every time, it should be OK, but if you are declaring a new function each time i'm not sure.

If it's a 1000 lines function in a loop that loop thousand times, sure you'll have problems ;)
Otherwise, don't over-optimize. Do what you think you should do, and only when you're done you can try to find some bottlenecks...